# Dozer generic mapping from multiple packages (wildcard?)

Tags: java, properties, dozer

Can I write converter for classes that exist in multiple packages? For example I have ClassA which exists in com.package.a.1, com.package.a.2 etc. ClassB exists in com.package.b.1, com.package.b.2 etc. Every copy of ClassA and ClassB has the same definition.

I've tried something like this, but no success

```
<converter type="com.package.MyConverter">
   <class-a>com.package.a.*.ClassA</class-a>
   <class-b>com.package.b.*.ClassB</class-b>
</converter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. If you consider it from a code point of view, how would it know what object to turn the class into? However, you can re-use the converter. e.g.

```
<converter type="com.package.MyConverter">
  <class-a>com.package.a.p1.ClassA</class-a>
  <class-b>com.package.b.p1.ClassB</class-b>
</converter>
<converter type="com.package.MyConverter">
  <class-a>com.package.a.p2.ClassA</class-a>
  <class-b>com.package.b.p2.ClassB</class-b>
</converter>
```

The only other possibility I can think of, is that if the attributes all have the same names, you don't need to specify the converter, or list them in the mapping, Dozer will just automatically convert everything with identical names.

(I could be wrong with what i've said, but this is what i've dealt with in my experience with Dozer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Interface for all your Classes you want to be mapped by your custom `com.package.MyConverter` mapper. So you only have do define the mapping once:

```
<converter type="com.package.MyConverter">
   <class-a>com.package.IMyConverterMappable</class-a>
   <class-b>com.package.IMyConverterMappable</class-b>
</converter>
```